# Buddypress: Load Ajax Without Template Pack

Tags: ajax, buddypress

How can I load buddypress ajax without using the template pack plugi n?
I had this in a non-buddypress compatible theme's functions.php.

```
include( BP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/ajax.php' );


function mytheme_enqueue_bp_default_js() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'dtheme-ajax-js', BP_PLUGIN_URL . '/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/global.js', array( 'jquery' ), bp_get_version() );

$params = array(
    'my_favs'           => __( 'My Favorites', 'buddypress' ),
    'accepted'          => __( 'Accepted', 'buddypress' ),
    'rejected'          => __( 'Rejected', 'buddypress' ),
    'show_all_comments' => __( 'Show all comments for this thread', 'buddypress' ),
    'show_all'          => __( 'Show all', 'buddypress' ),
    'comments'          => __( 'comments', 'buddypress' ),
    'close'             => __( 'Close', 'buddypress' ),
    'view'              => __( 'View', 'buddypress' ),
    'mark_as_fav'       => __( 'Favorite', 'buddypress' ),
    'remove_fav'        => __( 'Remove Favorite', 'buddypress' )
);
wp_localize_script( 'dtheme-ajax-js', 'BP_DTheme', $params );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_bp_default_js' );
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have used the default BP ajax queries/scripts in a custom BuddyPress theme:

(gist with code: https://gist.github.com/3154297 )

```
function bp_custom_include_ajax() {
  global $bp;
  require_once( BP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/ajax.php' );
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
    // Register buttons for the relevant component templates
    // Messages button
    if ( bp_is_active( 'messages' ) )
      add_action( 'bp_member_header_actions',    'bp_send_private_message_button' );
  }
      // Group buttons
    if ( bp_is_active( 'groups' ) ) {
      add_action( 'bp_group_header_actions',     'bp_group_join_button' );
      add_action( 'bp_group_header_actions',     'bp_group_new_topic_button' );
      add_action( 'bp_directory_groups_actions', 'bp_group_join_button' );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bp_custom_include_ajax', 11 );


function bp_custom_enqueue_global_script() {

    // Add words that we need to use in JS to the end of the page so they can be translated and still used.
  $params = array(
    'my_favs'           => __( 'My Favorites', 'buddypress' ),
    'accepted'          => __( 'Accepted', 'buddypress' ),
    'rejected'          => __( 'Rejected', 'buddypress' ),
    'show_all_comments' => __( 'Show all comments for this thread', 'buddypress' ),
    'show_all'          => __( 'Show all', 'buddypress' ),
    'comments'          => __( 'comments', 'buddypress' ),
    'close'             => __( 'Close', 'buddypress' )
  );

  // Bump this when changes are made to bust cache
  $version = '20120712';
  $params['view']     = __( 'View', 'buddypress' );

  // Enqueue the global JS - Ajax will not work without it
  wp_enqueue_script( 'dtheme-ajax-js', BP_PLUGIN_URL . '/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/global.js', array( 'jquery' ), $version );

  // Localize the JS strings
  wp_localize_script( 'dtheme-ajax-js', 'BP_DTheme', $params );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bp_custom_enqueue_global_script');
```

Comment: Awesome Rachel! I'm gonna test it in a non-bp  theme right now!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I found a quick solution myself, although it  doesn't load as fast as the ajax on the default theme.

In my functions.php, I have this:

```
<?php
require_once( BP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/ajax.php' );
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'bp-js', BP_PLUGIN_URL . '/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/global.js',
    array( 'jquery' ) 
);
?>
```

Comment: When one votes down, usually leaves a message indicating the reason. And it simply means something like "the question/answer is not well formulatted/researched/scoped" and you can revert it editing your Q&A. Don't take it personally and please check the FAQ ('cause you don't have the [Analytical](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/77/analytical) Badge ;)

Comment: Lol thanx Brasofilo.

Comment: I'm gonna get me an Analytical badge if its the last thing I do!

Comment: If anyone has a better way, feel free to share it, pwease :)! This does the job but it doesnt load as fast as the default theme's ajax. I wonder what Im missing